# Remove unused dll's from .net solution

Tags: .net, solution

My question is that is there any tool available in market to find all the unused dll's and  remove it from .net solution for visual studio 2012 to make it lighter.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper provides an option for removed unused references.

After installing Resharper just right click on the references of Project in solutions explorer, there you will get the menu (Optimize References) to removed unused references.

Link to Resharper: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ea4ac039-1b5c-4d11-804e-9bede2e63ecf

Comment: my requirement is to remove the unused dll's from the solution not the references.

Comment: Build your sources again and you will not have unused dll's. No ?

Comment: I have the library folder in my solution where project specific dll's are placed(which are added by me or by my project mates) if i will remove the references from the others project's then they are automatically removed or not ????

Comment: Ramis: It won't get automatically deleted..
Resharper has another one option called "Find Code Dependent on Module". this will used to identify, if the selected project/dll are used in the solution or not. You have to manually check all the projects/dll and you remove it manually.